# FileReader relative path

Tags: java, io, path, relative-path

I have a library, ShaderUtils, that I use in my games. Now, when I go to export my games with this library, it doesn't work correctly because the ShaderUtils try to load my shaders through a relative path. How can I fix this? I want it to load it like this:

```
image = ImageIO.read(Level.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("heightmap.bmp"));
```

I'm currently doing this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fragmentLoc));
```

I need the bufferedReader, but how can I change it so it will load like the image file?

Comment: BufferedImage has a constructor that takes an array of bytes. You don't need ImageIO at all for something simple like this. Just load up the file and make an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        Level.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("your_resource")
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you! Although there were a ton of great answers, yours was the best!

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like this:

```
new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        Level.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("your_resource")
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the FileReader. A resource isn't a file. Your first example shows how to get a resource as a stream. Wrap an InputStreamReader and then your BufferedReader around that.

Why you think you want a Reader to load an image file is another question, and not one that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try sth like, becouse ImageIO.read() can read file too.

[ImageIO.class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)

```
static BufferedImage read(File input) 
          Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied File with an ImageReader chosen automatically from among those currently registered.
```

so create a File file = new File("path");

and pass to the method.